# UI Bootstrap Modal text does not display

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-modal

I have this angular project and on the sign in page has a dropdown where you can either signin or register. When you click the register button it opens up a modal which allows you to enter your information. The problem is that any text I put inside the modal doesn't not show up. The text inside the buttons show up but not any other text. Any ideas?

**Login page template**

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu start-dropdown-btn">
        <li><a href="#">Signin with Username</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Signin with <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
        <li><a ng-click="registerWithUsername()" href><span class="text-success bold">Register now!</span></a></li>
     </ul>

</div>
```

**Modal template**

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="registerModal.html">
<div class="modal-body">
    <input id="registerUsername" placeholder="Enter Your Username" type="text" class="form-control top-spacer" ng-model="user.username" >
    <input id="registerPassword" placeholder="Enter Your Password" type="password" class="form-control top-spacer" ng-model="user.password">

</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <div class="btn-block">
        <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="register(user)">Sign Up</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="close()">Cancel</button>
    </div>
    <div role="alert" class="alert alert-info" ng-show="registrationSuccessMessage"></div>
</div>
</script>
```

**Login controller that opens modal**

```
$scope.registerWithUsername = function(){
        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            animation: true,
            templateUrl: 'registerModal.html',
            size: 'sm',
            controller: 'RegisterCtrl',
            resolve: {
                minutes: function(){
                    return $scope.settings
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

**Modal controller**

```
$scope.register = function(user_info){

        $scope.loading = true

        Register.save({
            username: user_info.username,
            password: user_info.password,
        })
}
```

Comment: Any errors in console?

Comment: Nope, no errors in console.